# When I add position:fixed to div, when I scroll page to top border of screen it does not work correctly on Safari OS X

Tags: macos, safari

If I add class ".affix" that contains css property "position:fixed;" to div when I have scrolled to top border of screen on Safari browser the block hops.

Answer (score 0):

https://stanko.github.io/ios-safari-scoll-position-fixed/

The problem was in translate3d CSS property. When I set `transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` to the element it helps.